# Version of mod-wsgi to use with django stack on python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

With Apt package manager `libapache2-mod-wsgi` can be easily installed which is giving `mod_wsgi-3.3`.

But I have seen at https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/master/

> Due to security issues in versions of mod_wsgi up to and including version 3.4, it is
>     recommended that version 3.5 or later be used.

So what is most suitable version of mod_wsgi to use with django stack running on python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django [will work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) with any version of Apache which supports mod_wsgi.

However, you will most likely want to build mod_wsgi from source using the same python you are using to run django.

Comment: then what is the stable / recommended version to work with django ?

Comment: I'd recommend version 4.4.0

Comment: What do you think about installing mod_wsgi as python package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi